# Issue in automating Java based application

Tags: java, qtp, hp-uft

I'm trying to automate Java based application using UFT. When I try to SPY the objects and create initial scripts, it worked without any issues.

But after sometime, the objects are not getting recognized and getting error like object not found. But the application is open and if I SPY the same object again, it remains with same properties I included in OR. It's really being a mystery for me!!!

When I tried to search several forums, I got to know the steps below for automating Java based application.

1. Navigate to the following registry key:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Mercury Interactive\JavaAgent\LoadDependsOnPackage - 32bit Operating System
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Mercury Interactive\JavaAgent\LoadDependsOnPackage - 64bit Operating System

2. Modify the value from “0” to "1". The default value is 0 which indicates that the agent is always loaded into an application. If this value is then changed to 1, it will instruct the agents to only be injected when QTP and the Java addin are loaded.
3. For changes to take effect, please restart the machine

But I'm facing that object recognition issue, even after making this change.

INCLUDING SAMPLE CODE *****

```
JavaWindow("JWnd_DatabaseAdministration").JavaTree("JTree_MenuNavig").Select "All Databases;DP2-Sample;DP1 [DB]"
JavaWindow("JWnd_DatabaseAdministration"). JavaTree("JTree_MenuNavig").Select
x = JavaWindow("JWnd_DatabaseAdministration").JavaTree("JTree_MenuNavig").GetROProperty("abs_x")
msgbox x
y = JavaWindow("JWnd_DatabaseAdministration").JavaTree("JTree_MenuNavig").GetROProperty("abs_y")
msgbox y
JavaWindow("JWnd_DatabaseAdministration").JavaTree("JTree_MenuNavig").Click x,y,"RIGHT"
JavaWindow("JWnd_DatabaseAdministration").JavaMenu("Properties").Select
```

Comment: Can you post some example code, perhaps from the beginning on the script to the point where you get "object not found"?

Comment: Yup, included some sample code above, it was working for me when I have written it, but now it throws "object not found" error.

Comment: 1. a) Does it work again after closing and restarting the AUT? b) After closing the AUT, QTP, then reopening QTP, then the AUT? 2. You AUt is not running in a browser, right?

Comment: 1. a) Initially worked, but after some time it didn't work b) Yes, first launched the QTP then only opened AUT. 2. Yes, AUT not running in browser. It's a windows based application.